# PowerShell: get all processes and save them to an xml file?

Tags: powershell-3.0

This code:

```
C:\> get-process | convertto-xml | out-file process.xml ; invoke-item process.xml
```

Results in this process.xml content:

```
xml                                Objects                           
---                                -------                           
version="1.0"                      Objects
```

How do we instead make it save the actual XML to the outfile instead of an object description? We want the XML to look like:

```
<process>
    <Handles>some value</Handles>
    <NPM(K)>some value</NPM(K)>
    <PM(K)>some value</PM(K)>      
    <WS(K)>some value</WS(K)>
    <VM(M)>some value</VM(M)> 
    <CPU(s)>some value</CPU(s)>    
    <Id>some value</Id>
    <ProcessName>some value</ProcessName>
</process>
<process>
    ....
</process>
<process>
    ....
</process>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual XML"? Describe what you want that output to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find commands involving XML you can do

```
Get-Command -noun *xml*
```

In your case you can use Export-Clixml like this:

Get-Process | Export-Clixml filename.xml